# How to override media.phtml file magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.2-p1

I want to resize the image on PLP but doing so is adding white space. For the same I got one solution to override the media.phtml file & then set keepFrame to false.

I am not able to locate the file path so that I can override it. Can someone guide me on the same?
How can I remove the white space & which file will be used & at which path it will be created.

Thanks,
Rashi

Answer (score 0):

You can override via two ways

1. Override in custom module: You can define the catalog_product_view.xml file where you can add your media file path and copy that media file in your template file.
2. Simplest way is to override it in theme: Here you can copy the file with the same directory path as available in the module-catalog.
   Forex:
   In Core Media.phtml is available in : vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml file
   Override this file you can copy in the theme: app/design/frontend/package/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml.
   Cache flush and media file will come from your theme.
   Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I didn't find any media.phtml file at given location. I didn't find catalog folder inside templates

Comment: @RashiGoyal I have given one example in my comment. If you want to override the media HTML section of the product details page then you need to refer vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Comment: But my query was that where to locate media.phtml file & I want to do this for PLP not for PDP. gallery.phtml will work in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by Overidding view.xml inside app/design/frontend/custom/theme/etc/view.xml

I changed the id category_page_grid with the required dimensions. Set aspect_ratio & frame value to false. It worked for me perfectly fine-

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>176</width>
                <height>273</height>
                <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
<image id="category_page_grid-1" type="small_image">
                <width>176</width>
                <height>273</height>
                <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
```

Thanks,
Rashi